# Method with Button button Parameters

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As suggested by others don't try to do `toString()` on any Android widget as it won't give you the text of the view.

Android widgets normally have `getText` instead.

In the case of creating a custom view avoid using `toString` to get the text as it won't follow Android practices.

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.getText().toString()` instead of `button.toString()` to get text from clicked Button.

```
 if (answer == Integer.valueOf(button.getText().toString())) {
        //.....code here..
 } else {
        //.....code here..
 }
```

Because when we call [View.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#toString%28%29) returns:

*a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object*

Comment: @user3674598: Welcome.sometimes we make small mistake to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Create View Click Listener instead of a method `checkAnswer()`, something like:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (answer == Integer.valueOf(but2.getText().toString())) {
                title.setText("Correct");
            } else {
                title.setText("GAME OVER");
            }
        }
}
```

and then set onClickListener for buttons:

```
but1.setOnClickListener(listener);
but2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably will be better if you change the checkAnswer method to:

```
private void checkAnswer(int value) {
if (answer == value) {
    title.setText("Correct");
} else {
    title.setText("GAME OVER");
}
}
```

That way will be more reusable. Then you can call it like this:

```
checkAnswer(Integer.valueOf(but1.getText().toString()))
```

Comment: It is a possible solution, although I have to get the string of a button and in some part of the code convert it to Integer, I will also try this out

Comment: The thing here is that your checkAnswer method should not depend on the presentation layer. Usually this checkAnswer method should be part of one of your models. So later if you want to change to use an image, or editText, instead of a button, you can still use that method.

Answer (score 0):

this is the proper way to do it:

In onCreate:

```
btn1.setOnCLickListener(this);

btn2.setOnCLickListener(this);
```

in onClick:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn1) {
            //do stuff related to button 1;
            } 
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn2) {
            //do stuff related to button 2;
            }
    }
```

implemet OnClickListener in your class

Answer (score 0):

```
For checking between string and parsing string into integer you have to do like this...


  if (answer == Integer.parseInt("String here") {
                    title.setText("Correct");
                } else {
                    title.setText("GAME OVER");
                }
```